# solve equation with loop

Tags: equation-solving, infinite-loop

I want to solve equation with different variable and list answers in a table
how can Solve it in a loop (Without repeating the equation)

```
a[1] = 14; b[1] = 16; c[1] = 3;
a[2] = 10; b[2] = 10; c[2] = 13;
a[3] = 19; b[3] = 15; c[3] = 7;
a[4] = 17; b[4] = 11; c[4] = 6;
Solve[{ E[1]*0.01 + F[1]*0.04 + a[1] == b[1], E[1]* 0.04 +  F[1]*0.02 + a[1] == c[1]}, {E[1], F[1]}]
Solve[{ E[2]*0.01 + F[2]*0.04 + a[2] == b[2], E[2]* 0.04 +  F[2]*0.02 + a[2] == c[2]}, {E[2], F[2]}]
Solve[{ E[3]*0.01 + F[3]*0.04 + a[3] == b[3], E[3]* 0.04 +  F[3]*0.02 + a[3] == c[3]}, {E[3], F[3]}]
olve[{ E[4]*0.01 + F[4]*0.04 + a[4] == b[4], E[4]* 0.04 +  F[4]*0.02 + a[4] == c[4]}, {E[4], F[4]}]
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, don't use capital letters, you'll run into trouble like you did there (`E` is defined as the natural log unit $e$).  You can do what you are going for with a `Table`,

```
a = {14, 10, 19, 17};
b = {16, 10, 15, 11};
c = {3, 13, 7, 6};

Table[
 {e, f} /. 
  First@Solve[{e*0.01 + f*0.04 + a[[n]] == b[[n]], 
     e*0.04 + f*0.02 + a[[n]] == c[[n]]}, {e, f}]
 , {n, 4}]

(* {{-342.857, 
  135.714}, {85.7143, -21.4286}, {-285.714, -28.5714}, {-228.571, \
-92.8571}} *)
```

Just to explain some of that notation, when I type `a[[n]]` it is accessing the $n^{th}$ element of the list `a`.  For the first case,

```
Solve[{e*0.01 + f*0.04 + a[[1]] == b[[1]], 
  e*0.04 + f*0.02 + a[[1]] == c[[1]]}, {e, f}]
(* {{e -> -342.857, f -> 135.714}} *)
```

Notice that `Solve` returns a list of replacement rules, so we use the `/.` notation

```
{e, f} /. {{e -> -342.857, f -> 135.714}}
(* {{-342.857, 135.714}} *)
```

But then we notice that it gives the answer with an extra pair of curly brackets around it (why? I don't know).  We can do away with those by using the `First` command, which is equivalent to typing `[[1]]` afterwards,

```
{e, f} /. First@{{e -> -342.857, f -> 135.714}}
(* {-342.857, 135.714} *)
```

So you just wrap that up in a `Table` and run it from 1 to 4.

If you want to learn about pure functions, and `Apply`, you could write it like this as well, and get the same result.

```
({e, f} /. 
    First@Solve[{e*0.01 + f*0.04 + #1 == #2, 
       e*0.04 + f*0.02 + #1 == #3}, {e, f}]) & @@@ Transpose@{a, b, c}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply to my problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = {14, 10, 19, 17};
b = {16, 10, 15, 11};
c = {3, 13, 7, 6};
eq[a_,b_,c_] := Solve[{e*0.01+f*0.04 +a ==b,e*0.04 +f*0.02 + a == c},{e, f}];
MapThread[eq, {a, b, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply to my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If the equation is linear (as in your example) a good built-in function to try is `LinearSolve`.

```
a = {14, 10, 19, 17};
b = {16, 10, 15, 11};
c = {3, 13, 7, 6};
```

Your equations can be re-written as:

```
e*0.01 + f*0.04 == b - a
e*0.04 + f*0.02 == c - a
```

So the matrix input to `LinearSolve` will be:

```
{{0.01, 0.04}, {0.04, 0.02}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`LinearSolve` allows a matrix to be the second argument in order to get multiple solutions.

For this case that matrix will be:

```
b2=b-a;
c2=c-a;

{b2,c2};
```

The output needs to be transposed:

```
Transpose@LinearSolve[{{0.01, 0.04}, {0.04, 0.02}}, {b2, c2}]
(* {{-342.857, 135.714}, {85.7143, -21.4286}, 
    {-285.714, -28.5714},{-228.571,-92.8571}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {14, 10, 19, 17};
b = {16, 10, 15, 11};
c = {3, 13, 7, 6};
arr = Array[m, {2, 4}];
sol=Solve[{{0.01, 0.04}.arr + a == b, {0.04, 0.02}.arr + a == c}, 
 Flatten[arr]]
```

yields:

```
{{m[1, 1] -> -342.857, m[1, 2] -> 85.7143, m[1, 3] -> -285.714, 
  m[1, 4] -> -228.571, m[2, 1] -> 135.714, m[2, 2] -> -21.4286, 
  m[2, 3] -> -28.5714, m[2, 4] -> -92.8571}}
```

If you want to extract e and f:

```
{e, f} = arr /. sol[[1]]
```